# I want to take the value of textarea and display the value at submit (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I searched without necessarily finding it. I would like to get the value of the `textarea` and at submit display the value in the paragraph of the `<AddNote />` component.

My project is to create a kind of application to take notes. You have to enter in a field the note then by validating the form, your note is added below.

Thanks to you and have a nice day

Into `note.js`

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import AddNote from './addnote';

class Note extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: '' };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className='title'>
                    <h1>Notes</h1>
                    <span className="LineTitle"></span>
                </div>
                <form id="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <textarea className="textNote" id="textZone" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" className="addBtn">Ajouter</button>
                    <button type="reset" className="deleteBtn">Supprimer</button>
                </form>

                <AddNote />
                
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Note;
```

Into `addnote.js`

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Note from './note';

class AddNote extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h3 className="NoteDetails">date/heure/minutes</h3>
                <span className="NoteLine"></span>
                <div className="notes">
                    <p></p> // the value of textarea into
                </div>

            </>
        )
    }
}

export default AddNote;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in your AddNote component changes depending on actions from its parent component (Note). So, you can add isTextDisplayed to Note component's state

```
this.state = { value: '', isTextDisplayed: false };
```

And then you change it on submit like this

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ isTextDisplayed: true });
}
```

Pass it into your child component

```
<AddNote text={ this.state.value } isTextDisplayed={ this.state.isTextDisplayed } />
```

And use it inside AddNote

```
<p>{ this.props.isTextDisplayed && this.props.text }</p>
```

That is it! In the future if you want to show multiple notes, you will need to store an array of notes in state and render them using a loop

Answer (score 0):

Just send the value of state to the chiild component and use it there as props :

```
<AddNote note={this.state.value} />
```

and in AddNote component use it like :

```
<p>{this.props.note}</p>
```